# Add crossorigin to SCRIPT tag

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

Is there any way to add a `crossorigin` attribute to a custom registered JavaScript?

```
wp_register_script('foo', 'http://cdn.domain.com/script.min.js', null, '1.2.3');
wp_enqueue_script( 'bar', '/path/to/bar.js', array( 'foo' ), '20170912' );
```

Answer (score 1):

[`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) or `script_loader_src` filters are there to let you tweak the HTML of the script easily so you can add custom attributes:

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function($tag, $handle){
    switch ( $handle ) {
        case 'foo':
            $tag = preg_replace(
                '/src=[\'|"|]/i',
                'crossorigin $0',
                $tag
            );
            break;
    }

    return $tag;
}, 10, 2);
```

To avoid conflicting with other plugins, pass unique handles to the script/style register/enqueue function, `foo` in your case:

`wp_register_script('foo', 'http://cdn.domain.com/script.min.js', null, '1.2.3');`

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_register_script/wp_enqueue_script functions, you can't do that. Maybe open the ticket with WordPress TRAC to be implemented in future versions.